# Google Marketplace Add-on not loading for some users

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I have a couple add-ons published on the Google Workspace Marketplace and for nearly all of the users everything runs fine. But for just two users it will not run properly in Chrome. The execution just hangs for no discernable reason. It is not occurring with specific functions and the same add-on works fine for me and other users.

What's even stranger is it runs completely fine in Microsoft Edge browser for these two.

I've had them try clearing their browser cache and then uninstalling and reinstalling the add-on with no luck. Has anyone else encountered something like this? Anything else I can have them try?

Comment: Ask these users to try using Chrome in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled and using a different device. If you need further help, please add more programming / debugging details, i.e. Chrome version the name and version of the operative systems, the type of account used, the dev-tools console logs, (user dependent), the execution logs (from Google Apps Script / Cloud Logging), etc.

Comment: See if [Unexpected "authorization is required" error](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69270374) is relevant to you. Click the star icon ☆ in the top left-hand corner to vote for fixing the issue and get notified of status changes. Please do not post a "me too" or "+1" reply, but just click the star icon. Google prioritizes issues with the most stars.